# I want to create a linear regression scatterplot for an assignment. State names are giving me an error (?)

Tags: macos, regression, linear-regression, analysis, sklearn-pandas

I am working on a project tracking poverty across the US between 1995 and 2020.

As I am working on a linear regression scatterplot, I have this:

```
# Create a regression object.
regression = LinearRegression()  
# This is the regression object, which will be fit onto the training set.

# Fit the regression object onto the training set.
regression.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

With the following error message:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'New Hampshire'
```

Assuming this is due to New Hampshire being two words instead of one; Is this correct?
How can I get it to assign a _ between States which have this issue:

New Hampshire
New Jersey
New Mexico
New York
North Carolina
North Dakota
Rhode Island
South Carolina
South Dakota
West Virginia

Pre-error code and error in full below.

```
# Create a regression object.
regression = LinearRegression()  
# This is the regression object, which will be fit onto the training set.

# Fit the regression object onto the training set.
regression.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

With the following error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[55], line 3
      1 # Fit the regression object onto the training set.
----> 3 regression.fit(X_train, y_train)

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_base.py:648, in LinearRegression.fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    644 n_jobs_ = self.n_jobs
    646 accept_sparse = False if self.positive else ["csr", "csc", "coo"]
--> 648 X, y = self._validate_data(
    649     X, y, accept_sparse=accept_sparse, y_numeric=True, multi_output=True
    650 )
    652 sample_weight = _check_sample_weight(
    653     sample_weight, X, dtype=X.dtype, only_non_negative=True
    654 )
    656 X, y, X_offset, y_offset, X_scale = _preprocess_data(
    657     X,
    658     y,
   (...)
    661     sample_weight=sample_weight,
    662 )

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:584, in BaseEstimator._validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
    582         y = check_array(y, input_name="y", **check_y_params)
    583     else:
--> 584         X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
    585     out = X, y
    587 if not no_val_X and check_params.get("ensure_2d", True):

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:1106, in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, estimator)
   1101         estimator_name = _check_estimator_name(estimator)
   1102     raise ValueError(
   1103         f"{estimator_name} requires y to be passed, but the target y is None"
   1104     )
-> 1106 X = check_array(
   1107     X,
   1108     accept_sparse=accept_sparse,
   1109     accept_large_sparse=accept_large_sparse,
   1110     dtype=dtype,
   1111     order=order,
   1112     copy=copy,
   1113     force_all_finite=force_all_finite,
   1114     ensure_2d=ensure_2d,
   1115     allow_nd=allow_nd,
   1116     ensure_min_samples=ensure_min_samples,
   1117     ensure_min_features=ensure_min_features,
   1118     estimator=estimator,
   1119     input_name="X",
   1120 )
   1122 y = _check_y(y, multi_output=multi_output, y_numeric=y_numeric, estimator=estimator)
   1124 check_consistent_length(X, y)

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:879, in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator, input_name)
    877         array = xp.astype(array, dtype, copy=False)
    878     else:
--> 879         array = _asarray_with_order(array, order=order, dtype=dtype, xp=xp)
    880 except ComplexWarning as complex_warning:
    881     raise ValueError(
    882         "Complex data not supported\n{}\n".format(array)
    883     ) from complex_warning

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_array_api.py:185, in _asarray_with_order(array, dtype, order, copy, xp)
    182     xp, _ = get_namespace(array)
    183 if xp.__name__ in {"numpy", "numpy.array_api"}:
    184     # Use NumPy API to support order
--> 185     array = numpy.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
    186     return xp.asarray(array, copy=copy)
    187 else:

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'New Hampshire'

# Predict the values of y using X.
```

Assuming this is due to New Hampshire being two words instead of one; Is this correct?
How can I get it to assign a _ between States which have this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Using the advice from @some3128 I looked a bit into `LinearRegression`, `OneHotCoder` and `sklearn`.

What I found was I could use `LabelEncoder` to assign dummy numbers to the states, and go from there.

```
    ## Using LabelEncoder I need to give the States numbers. I have been running int an issue/error as follows:
## ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'New_Hampshire'
## Using LabelEncoder should fix this.

label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
df_sub1['State_encoded'] = label_encoder.fit_transform(df_sub1['State'])
print(df_sub1.head())
```

This assigned each state a number, sequentially, which then allowed me to run my tests.

```
       State  Percent in poverty  Year  State_encoded
561     Alabama                  17  2010              0
562      Alaska                  13  2010              1
563     Arizona                  19  2010              2
564    Arkansas                  15  2010              3
565  California                  16  2010              4
```

Then the following, and all ran smoothly after that!

```
# Reshape the variables into NumPy arrays and put them into separate objects.

X = df_sub1['State_encoded'].values.reshape(-1,1)
y = df_sub1['Percent in poverty'].values.reshape(-1,1)
```

Comment: Nice. This is one way of generating numbers from categories. The documentation advises that `LabelEncoder` should be used for encoding the target (y) of your regression, rather than the input X. In your case, the column you are encoding is part of the X (not y), and in such cases the standard practice is use `OneHotEncoder`, `OrdinalEncoder`, or something else intended for encoding X-related data. Though it might not matter much in your case if you're happy with the results.

Comment: A point about the choice of encoding: when you encode categories onto a numerical scale (0, 1, 2...) , the linear regression coefficients will assume there is meaning in that scale. This is undesirable when the categories aren't numerically related to eachother (e.g. they're just a list of separate names). `OneHotEncoding` is more correct for such cases, and will give you more meaningful coefficients in the linear regression. If you are not interested in interpreting the coefficients, and only need the prediction, then it might not matter.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are strings in the dataframe. `LinearRegression` is expecting numbers only. You'll need to convert the strings to numbers using `OneHotEncoder` or similar. That will look at how many *unique* strings (unique categories) there are, and then each string (category) will be represented numerically using one-hot encoding. Regression can then work with that numerical representation of the categories.

Comment: Ok. But can you explain why the FIRST error was 'New Hampshire' and none of the other state names were flagged? (Alabama through Nebraska)...  ? 

Seems like its not expecting numbers, just unbroken strings that can be parsed/converted  into floats.

Says so right in the last line.

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'New Hampshire'

So how do the previous state names NOT get flagged as an error?

Comment: It probably crashes at the first place it sees a string, which is why it names just one string. Once it hits an error condition, it won't look at or try to process the rest.

Comment: Fair. 

But the data column is named 'State' and lists State names, which puts New Hampshire at 28th in the list. Why not throw the error up at 'Alabama', the first state? This is where I am having a hard time understanding the error.

If all State names are invalid, why does it SPECIFICALLY say 
[ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'New Hampshire'] 

That says to my dumb-brain that every State BEFORE it was fine.

Comment: I don't know why it errored at the 28th row specifically, rather than the first. I can see why this behaviour suggests the first 27 rows looked fine. It might be to do with how the function works behind the scenes, which could include shuffling, sorting, or processing data in an optimised order. Ultimately, it will package the results so that they match the order you supplied them in, unless it crashes part-way through.